# Need help with error- The name 'lnk1' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my link button:-

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" Text="Set as Default" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="lnk1_OnClick"></asp:LinkButton>
```

In Code Behind I am simply making it visible

```
lnk1.Visible = true;
```

I have checked the IDs over n over..whats wrong ? Intellisense wont detect it either..I am doing something really silly..just cant figure what it is ..help!

I even restarted Visual Studio..still same error

Comment: what does your @page directive look like, what about the class declartion (public partial class XX) and what's the name of the code behind file? and what version of ASP.NET?

Comment: @rune ::rest of the code works alright when I make these two lines commented out

Comment: Just trying to help :) It's perfectly possible to have the rest of the code work. E.g. if you are inheriting your codebehind (not using partial which would be visible from the class declaration) you could have forgotten to declare your control. If you use partial but derives from a base page then the rest could work even if your @page directive was wrong (wrong codebehind file) so just because everytinhg else work doesn't rule out the above just makes it less likely :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the contol part of another control template? E.G. part of a repeaters ItemTemplate etc?

**Update:**

Since OP has said it's part of a repeaters ItemTemplate, just thought I'd explain what to do (Even though OP has sorted it)

You need to call FindControl on the Repeater, or Controls.OfType() depending on the situation, to get the control.

ASP:

```
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrTest">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBxName" />
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBx1" />
            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBx2" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

C#

```
        IEnumerable<CheckBox> chkBoxes = rptrTest.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
        TextBox txtBxName = (TextBox)rptrTest.FindControl("txtBxName");
```

What I'll often do for commonly used controls (though wether it's a good idea or not I'm sure someone will now let me know), is create a member which executes this code.

```
    private TextBox _txtBxName;
    public TextBox txtBxName {
        get {
            if (_txtBxName == null) {
                _txtBxName = (TextBox)rptrTest.FindControl("txtBxName");
            }
            return _txtBxName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes its inside of ItemTemplate of Repeater control..so now what ?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the designer class is not re-generated correctly. Things you can try:

- select the line, cut, save, rebuild,
  paste back, save
- delete the designer
  .cs file, right click the aspx,
  convert to web application -> this
  will generate the designer class from
  scratch

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have the *rights* to comment; so ...

- In which event you are making that item visible? try doing that in PageLoad.
- Can you show your markups?

Alternatively, you can try to [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) the control.

Comment: it wouldn't be a compile error but a potential null reference exception if that was the case