# How to Bind and Insert in Repeater control in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, repeater

I have created the table `cm_table` and `cm_table_copy` on MySQL database.

On `cm_table` I have recorded three rows, instead the `cm_table_copy` is empty

After that added new web form to website.

Drag and drop a `Repeater control` from Toolbox>Data to .aspx page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Repeater.aspx.cs" Inherits="Repeater" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Repeater ID="repcomment" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: Red; margin-left: 10px;">
                        Repeater control in Asp.net
                        </legend>
                        <div class="pure-g">
                            <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
                                Comment
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txComment" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comment").ToString()%>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <div class="container">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btn" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Validation2" 
                                OnClick="btn_Click"
                                ImageUrl="/Images/edit_button.gif" 
                                OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Confirm?')) return false;"
                                CausesValidation="true" />
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" 
             ValidationGroup="Validation2" runat="server" 
             ShowSummary="false"
             ShowMessageBox="true" 
             CssClass="validation-summary-errors" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I should see on the web browser the three rows recorded on `cm_table` and when the comment on `cm_table` is edited I need register the new comment on `cm_table_copy`

But I have this error on first access to aspx page

> CS0103: The name 'txComment' does not exist in the current context

How to do resolve this?

My `code-behind` below

Can you help me, please?

Thank you in advance for any help

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class Repeater : Page
{
    protected void btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = String.Format(" INSERT INTO cm_table_copy (Comment, LatestComment) ");
        sql += String.Format(" VALUES(?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()); ");

        using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
           new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ca"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (OdbcCommand command =
               new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", txComment.Text.Replace("'", "`").ToString().ToUpper()); //<<<Line of error
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM cm_table; ");

            using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
                new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ca"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (OdbcCommand command =
                    new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        command.Connection.Open();

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                        OdbcDataAdapter adp = new OdbcDataAdapter(command);
                        adp.Fill(ds);

                        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            repcomment.DataSource = ds;
                            repcomment.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        command.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update #01**

I have tried this but the `FindControl` always returns null

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txComment = (TextBox)repcomment.FindControl("txComment");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help with error- The name 'lnk1' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930999/need-help-with-error-the-name-lnk1-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Use FindControl since there can be multiple `txComment` in the Repeater.

Comment: @VDWWD thanks for suggestion, please see **update #01** on the question

Comment: A Repeater is index based. `TextBox txComment = (TextBox)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("txComment");`

Comment: @VDWWD thanks, now working correctly!